# Is third Blade slot restricted by plot?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

I'm now on third available location of Xenoblade Chronicles 2, and I've stocked on a lot of crystal cores so far, so I've decided to set extra Blades for my characters for more vast combos selection, and more flexibility in combat in general. Yet, it seems, I cannot assign third Blade for characters - slot is simply not selectable in Engage Blades menu.

So, is it restricted by plot, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The third blade slot is unlocked in chapter 4. I've just unlocked it now.

Comment: There is already correct answer, that it is restricted by plot. If you think some details are incorrect (e.g. specified chapter), please consider to update this answer instead.

Comment: @lentinant Edits are not supposed to change an answer's content, even if it's wrong. That's what new answers are for.

Comment: @lentinant Ageeed with Danmaku. If the answer is wrong, it shouldn’t be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the third blade slot is restricted by the main story. You'll get it sometime in chapter 2, if I remember right.

Comment: I'm on chapter 3 and I don't have it yet so while this answer may be correct the when needs to be fixed.